# How to add a fragment in a compose navhost without re-writing entire code

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

So we refactored our app to start using Jetpack compose problem is we encountered a problem. So it was easy to refactor the other screens but when it came to this main screen it has more logic and refactoring will take long time hence we just need to launch the fragment on the `composable(Destination.Transaction.route) {launch fragment}`

So I have seen sample code on how that can be done, but currently using this; Android

```
AndroidViewBinding(FragmentTransactionsBinding::inflate) {}
```

So here is my `TranscationFragment` question is how can I open this fragment on the composable I have been trying all tricks with no success.-

```
class TransactionsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_transactions) {
    private var preference: SharedPreferences? = null
    private var symbol = ""
    private val expenseViewModel: ExpenseViewModel by viewModel()
    private var binding: FragmentTransactionsBinding? = null

    private val simpleMonthFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy", Locale.US)
    private val tabDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.US)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentTransactionsBinding.bind(view)
        preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
        //fetch symbol by iso code in preference
        val currency: ArrayList<ExtendedCurrency> = ArrayList()
        for (c in ExtendedCurrency.getAllCurrencies()) {
            currency.add(c)
            val code = preference?.getString("selectedCurrency", "")
            if (c.code == code)
                symbol = c.symbol
        }

        ((activity) as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding?.transactionsToolbar)

        if ((activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar != null)
            (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setTitle(R.string.transactions)

        binding?.fab?.setOnClickListener { openExpenseActivity() }
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            expenseViewModel.expensesDatesMap.observeForever(expenseDatesMapObserver)
        }else {
            expenseViewModel.expensesDatesMap.observeForever(expenseDatesMapObserver)
        }
    }
    private val expenseDatesMapObserver = Observer<Map<String, ArrayList<ExpenseData>>> {
        val tabs: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        val fragments = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        val dates: List<Date> = it.map { simpleMonthFormat.parse(it.key) }
        var amount = 0.0
        if (dates.isNotEmpty()) {
            var minDate: Date? = dates[0]
            var maxDate: Date? = dates[0]
            for (date in dates) {
                minDate = min(minDate, date)
                maxDate = max(maxDate, date)
            }
            val beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            beginCalendar.time = minDate
            finishCalendar.time = maxDate
            var flag = true
            while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar) || flag) {
                val date = simpleMonthFormat.format(beginCalendar.time).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)
                if (date.equals(
                        simpleMonthFormat.format(finishCalendar.time).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT),
                        ignoreCase = true
                    )
                ) flag = false
                tabs.add(simpleMonthFormat.format(beginCalendar.time).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
                val monthFragment: Fragment = MonthlyFragment()
                val monthBundle = Bundle()
                for ((key, value) in it) {
                    if (date.equals(key, ignoreCase = true)) {
                        var totalExpenseAmount = 0.0
                        var totalIncomeAmount = 0.0
                        for (expenseData in value) {
                            expenseData.currency = preference?.getString("selectedCurrency", "")!!
                            if (expenseData.expenseType == "Expense")
                                totalExpenseAmount += expenseData.expenseAmount
                            else totalIncomeAmount += expenseData.expenseAmount
                        }
                        amount -= totalExpenseAmount
                        amount += totalIncomeAmount
                        monthBundle.putDouble("totalExpenseAmount", totalExpenseAmount)
                        monthBundle.putDouble("walletBalance", amount)
                        monthBundle.putParcelableArrayList("expensedatas", value)
                        Timber.d("value $value")
                        break
                    }
                }
                monthFragment.arguments = monthBundle
                fragments.add(monthFragment)
                beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
            }
        } else {
            val monthBundle = Bundle()
            tabs.add(tabDateFormat.format(Date().time).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
            val monthFragment: Fragment = MonthlyFragment()
            monthFragment.arguments = monthBundle
            fragments.add(monthFragment)
        }
        val adapter = PagerAdapter(this.childFragmentManager, fragments, tabs)

        binding?.viewpager?.adapter = adapter
        binding?.viewpager?.currentItem = binding?.viewpager?.adapter?.count!!
        binding?.tabs?.setupWithViewPager(binding?.viewpager)

        binding?.viewpager?.adapter?.count?.let { count ->
            if (count > 3)
                binding?.tabs?.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE
        }
    }
```

MainActivity Class:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun AppNavigation(navController: NavHostController) {

        val context = LocalContext.current
        NavHost(navController, startDestination = Destination.Transaction.route) {
            composable(Destination.Transaction.route) {
                
// Add Fragment instead of composable.

            }
            composable(Destination.Budgets.route) {
    
            }
         
            composable(Destination.Settings.route) {
                Settings()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "Just opens a fragment that action can't be performed on." mean?

Comment: please provide the code of your Activity and your NavHost implementation. It's difficult to answer with the code your provided. Matter of fact the Fragment code you provided is utterly irrelevant to your question and does not help in providing an answer.

Comment: Edited the question, @ianhanniballake I just want to open an old fragment there without re-writing the entire code.

Comment: And that's what `AndroidViewBinding` does - just adds the fragment to your composition. What exactly is the problem you're facing then?

Comment: Am not able to make the fragment act as it should. It has a floating action button but I can't click it.